# How to create Split View in menu strip in visual studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an editor for designing codes in which I need to create a menustrip item that splits the view in either horizontal or vertical orientation. I have seen many articles but didn't get any help. It's [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) based. Also the editor is a tabbed one. So the split functionality should work one each tab.

Comment: Depends on what type of app (WPF, WinForms, Web-based).

Comment: Its a winfrm application

Comment: You didn't add a winforms tag to the question.

Comment: And there is a splitter control for WinForms. Did you look at the available controls?

Comment: i have looked at it but have no idea how to use call splitter functionality on menustrip item click..

Comment: @Arie: That has absolutely nothing to do with this question,

Comment: @JonathanWood sorry, I didn't really understood the question then...

Comment: guys i dont think u understood the question..what i meant to say was i want to create multiple windows in a same tab in the editor like Brackets in which u can split the view to load different documents

Comment: @Ammy: I did understand. That's why I pointed out the splitter control, and why I indicated Arie's link wasn't relevant. There must be tons of information about this control on the web, and frankly I figured it out without using any other information. Why do you think I didn't understand the question? Someone else had to update your tags.

Comment: @Arie: Then you should delete the link.

Comment: @jonathan: i want to incur a split window functionality so that the user can code at two different windows in a same tab

Comment: @Ammy: In order for you to think I don't know that, I can only assume that you haven't even looked at the splitter control. It took literally seconds for me to find a video about it. I feel you are not trying. You couldn't even add a tag to your question when I pointed it out. If you don't think I understand what you are asking then fine. I'm through here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SplitContainer** and by default **two panels** let's say *panel1 and panel2* are added in **Vertical orientation**.

If you are using Visual Studio Designer than select the container and change the **Orientation** to **Vertical** or **Horizontal** according to your need.

To remove one panel, you can use either **panel1Collapsed** or **panel2Collapsed** boolean methods.

Remainig you can figure it out according to your needs.